# scrapy blocked with redis

Tags: python, redis, scrapy, yield

I use a scrapy spider to act as a consumer,there is also a producer to produce urls  and put them in redis irregularly,my codes are as follows:

```
def start_requests(self): 
    for msg in self.redis_sub.listen():
        data = json.loads(msg['data'].decode('utf-8'))
        id = data['id']
        styleUrl = data['styleUrl']
        pageCount = data['pageCount']
        self.obi.public(json.dumps({'id': id, 'isSynchronized': 1}))
        yield SplashRequest(url=styleUrl, callback=self.specHome_parse,
                                args={'wait': 5, 'timeout': 60, 'images': 0},
                                meta={'pageCount': pageCount, 'id': id, 'dont_redirect': True})
```

the codes can receive urls normally,but when it blocked in the second line to wait for urls,the all scrapy paused,includding the requests yielded before. I supposed it should have continued run old requesets,what is the reason and how to sovle it? help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fimiliar with Scrapy-Redis,I just know it use redis by lpush urls,but my I have to use publish/subscription in redis,so I adopt such a method:

```
    def start_requests(self):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = self.redis_sub.parse_response(block=False, timeout=5)
            if msg[0] != b'message':
                continue
            data = json.loads(msg[2].decode('utf-8'))
            id = data['id']
            styleUrl = data['styleUrl']
            pageCount = data['pageCount']
            self.obi.public(json.dumps({'id': id, 'isSynchronized': 1}))
            yield SplashRequest(url=styleUrl, callback=self.specHome_parse,
                                args={'wait': 5, 'timeout': 60, 'images': 0},
                                meta={'pageCount': pageCount, 'id': id, 'dont_retry': True})
        except Exception as e:
            yield SplashRequest()
            print(e)
```

and it proved to be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Scrapy-Redis](https://scrapy-redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of reinventing the wheel. See [Feeding a Spider from Redis](https://scrapy-redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#feeding-a-spider-from-redis).